# Using a Calculated Column to Total Date Based on Two Other Columns

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a 'Park' column and a 'Status' column on the same list. I'd like to created a calculated column called 'Total'. This column would use a formula to read the 'Park' column to determine the number of times a specific park appears AND also is shown as "compliant" in the 'Status' column. I've tried several COUNT and COUNTIF iterations, with no luck. Is this doable?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but I think you are trying to iterate the whole list? E.g. your list has 10 items and 5 items have value of 'Park' you want 5 as your result correct?

Comment: Negative; I have two columns. One column has a list of parks, and the parks may appear once or several times. I also have a status column that reads either compliant or noncompliant. I am looking for a formula that calculates the number of times a park appears in the 'Park' column that also are compliant in the 'Status' column. Meaning I may have 5 Jellystones, but only 3 are compliant, so my formula would return a total of 3.

Comment: SharePoint Calculated fields only works on single row so I am afraid I don't think you can achieve this OOTB. You will have to write some custom code.  REST API with some Ajax might be an option

Answer (score 0):

One may use only a small subset of Excel functions with SharePoint Calculated Columns. Please find reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx).

For your requirement, change field type to number column and use event receiver or workflows to update value of the field.

Comment: I can't change the field type, the action would adversely impact other queries and workflows. Which column are you suggesting be changed?Can I create another column that has a number in place of the text?

Answer (score 0):

For Functions that do work in SP see:

- http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

Your Formula can not be created in SharePoint because SharePoint is not Excel;
Formulas only work on the current Item; they have no clue there are other Item-Rows

You can create a View with Sum/Totals and Filter on Status equals "complaint"

Comment: I would need to identify a specific park first, before sorting by Status. How would I achieve that. Seems you option would show all 'compliant'. My end goal is to be able to tally the number of compliant of all parks, no matter how many times a park appears in the list, and push that number to another summary list.

Comment: Uncollapse all section when you modify a View. SharePoint is not Excel, You can Group By a View to 2 levels, and sum/total Fields within those Groups.. that's it